# Migrating existing Debinan installation to LVM on LUKS with encrypted /boot

Tags: boot, debian, grub, disk-encryption, luks

I have a VirtualBox with Debian Jessie. After some point I decided to create new virtual drive, encrypt it with LUKS, and copy old system to it without reinstalling.
I've used several guides ([1](http://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/),[2](http://ada.adrianlang.de/existing-debian-luks),[3](http://www.finnie.org/2009/07/26/howto-encrypt-an-existing-debian-installation/),[4](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system)) to do this, but something goes wrong - when I'm trying to boot from the second drive, I'm getting black screen with cursor (not even sure if it blinks). Looks like that is some kind of a grub related problem.

What was before is just a system on a single partition:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 40136703 40134656 19,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       40138750 41940991  1802242  880M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       40138752 41940991  1802240  880M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

New disk is /dev/sdb 40Gb. I've prepared this drive as in [1](http://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/), then mounted this drive and copied everything from the old system:

```
# mount /dev/mapper/vg-root /mnt/
# mount /dev/mapper/vg-home /mnt/home
# cp -a /bin /boot /etc /home /lib /root /sbin /usr /var /mnt
```

Then chrooted into the new system:

```
# mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
# mount -t sysfs none /mnt/sys
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
# chroot /mnt
```

Modified fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/vg-root     /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/vg-home     /home               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/mapper/vg-swap     none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Added changes to crypttab, initramfs and grub:

```
# echo 'lvm /dev/sda2 none luks' >> /etc/crypttab
# echo 'lvm2
  dmcrypt' >> /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
# update-initramfs -k all -u
```

Added options to /et/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=UUID=3bd9c402-92aa-4bf8-9644-7c7a079e1cf6:lvm"
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
```

then installed grub `# dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` and verified /boot/grub/grub.cfg ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Vgb7hpHH))

---

After trying to boot from this second drive I'm getting black screen with cursor. No errors, not texts of any kind. I think that even grub wasn't started...

Any ideas except to reinstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this. Looks like either `# dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` works somewhat different comparing to "grub-mkconfig - grub-install" way or I've used it wrong.

Anyway, I've installed it by executing

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
# grub-install /dev/sdb
```

just as [Pavel Kogan](http://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/) wrote and now grub boots.